# Razor escape colon inline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I escape colon in my razor code?

This is my issue:

```
@count@:: @item.Title - @item.Link - @item.Price
```

Which is causing an error after the @count variable. How am I able to use the colon next to my count?

It should render like this:

```
1: Title - Link - Price
```

** UPDATE **

My codeblock

```
@{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model.Wishes) {
        count++;
        @count@:: @item.Title - @item.Link - @item.Price
        <br />
    }
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with `@count:`?

Comment: Can't you use @count:

Comment: Is count a variable defined elsewhere, or are you using a model?

Comment: Count is defined as a variable elsewhere

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to wrap your display part of the code in `<text>` tags. The colon does not need to be escaped.

```
@{
    int count = 0;

    foreach (var item in Model.Wishes) {
        count++;
        <text>
        @count: @item.Title - @item.Link - @item.Price
        <br />
        </text>
    }
}
```

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

> The `<text>` tag is an element that is treated specially by Razor. It causes Razor to interpret the inner contents of the `<text>` block as content, and to not render the containing `<text>` tag element (meaning only the inner contents of the `<text>` element will be rendered – the tag itself will not).  This makes it convenient when you want to render multi-line content blocks that are not wrapped by an HTML element.

https://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax#BM_CombiningTextMarkupAndCode

> Use the `@:` operator or the `<text>` element. The `@:` outputs a single line of content containing plain text or unmatched HTML tags; the `<text>` element encloses multiple lines to output. These options are useful when you don't want to render an HTML element as part of the output.

Comment: I've been using razor for years, but this little trick passed me by. Solves quite a few problems :)

Answer (score 0):

If count is declared as a variable, then this should work.

```
@{
   var count = 4;
}

   @count:
```

If count is part of your model, then this should work.

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.DemoViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>



@Model.Count:
```